# Local grunt installation gives error

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

```
npm install -g grunt-cli   //done successfully

npm install grunt --save --only=dev
```

gives following error

```
    (node:11000) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If 
you are using the graceful
-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
npm WARN prefer global coffee-script@1.10.0 should be installed with -g
project@1.0.0 C:\Users\Live\Desktop\node grunt\final
`-- (empty)
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Tried uninstalling grunt-cli, cleaning npm cache, then re-installing, but still the problem persists.

Comment: What node and npm version are you running? What is the result of `node -v` and `npm -v`?

Comment: node - v6.11.2.....npm - 3.6.0

Comment: Ok. Try updating your npm: `npm update -g npm`. If that doesn't work either, remove your local `node_modules` folder and do a fresh `npm install` - Btw... `grunt-cli` and `grunt` are not the same thing

Comment: After this (npm update -g npm), it not creating node_modules folder at all with this command (npm install grunt --save --only=dev ), rather it's generating a package-lock.json. I don't know what is that for.

Comment: It defines what package versions you are using. What about `npm install` by itself?

Comment: It worked but it seems a bit weird to do `npm install` after doing `npm install grunt --save --only=dev`. node modules folder gets generated only after npm install.

Comment: Exactly, because when you do `npm install <package-name>` it only installs that one package. Is your problem now fixed?

Comment: My problem is fixed. But NPM install package name used to install all the dependencies of the package as well

Comment: Okay. Maybe they changed the behavior of `npm` then.

Comment: Thanks. You can add this as an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok short recap:

1. When in doubt remove your `node_modules` and install all packages again using `npm install`
2. If that didn't work, try updating your `npm` by executing `npm update -g npm` and redo step 1.
3. If that didn't solve your problem, try upgrading to another NodeJS version using [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md) or [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n).